# How to join and divide unknown number of columns in a dataframe with columns in another dataframe with same name dynamically

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

[image]

And most importantly number of col1, col2....are not known, there can be hundreds of columns. So we will have to do the join and division dynamically

How to this is spark scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset objects have the `columns` property that gives you an array of column names. It is easy to filter the columns of `df1` and leave those that are present in `df2`, then use `map` to derive the needed columns:

```
val df1 = Seq(("xyz", 10.0, 12.0),
              ("abc", 42.0, 7.0)).toDF("join_col", "col1", "col2")
val df2 = Seq(("xyz", 7.0, 22.0, 11.0),
              ("abc", 11.0, 9.0, 42.0)).toDF("join_col", "col1", "col2", "col3")

// Common columns in both datasets
val cols = df1.columns.filter(df2.columns.toSet)

val join_col = cols(0)

val joined = df1.join(df2, df1(join_col) === df2(join_col))

// Columns from df1
val df1Cols = cols.map(df1(_))

// Division columns renamed to div_whatever
val divCols = cols.drop(1).map((name) => df1(name) / df2(name) as s"div_${name}")

val finalTable = joined.select((df1Cols ++ divCols) :_*)

finalTable.show(false)
// +--------+----+----+------------------+------------------+
// |join_col|col1|col2|div_col1          |div_col2          |
// +--------+----+----+------------------+------------------+
// |xyz     |10.0|12.0|1.4285714285714286|0.5454545454545454|
// |abc     |42.0|7.0 |3.8181818181818183|0.7777777777777778|
// +--------+----+----+------------------+------------------+
```

This one assumes that the join column is the first column in `df1`.